# Why is JSoup printing a question mark

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, jsoup

I'm trying to understand the following. I have some code reading a page from gutenberg.org. Almost everything is ok but some characters are not. They are ok in the browser.

```
package nl.atticworks.gutenberg;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Gutenberg {

    private static final String GET_URL = "http://www.gutenberg.org/browse/languages/nl";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(GET_URL).get();
            Elements data = doc.select("div.pgdbbylanguage");
            for (Element d : data) {
                Elements children = d.select("*");
                for (Element child : children) {
                    if (child.tagName().equals("ul")) {
                        Element author = children.get(children.indexOf(child) - 1);
                        String a1 = author.select("a:last-child").text();
                        if (a1.startsWith("Kara")) {
                            System.out.println(a1);
                            Elements titles = child.select("li.pgdbetext a");
                            for (Element title : titles) {
                                System.out.println("\t" + title.text());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // do something...
        }
    }
}
```

The string a1 prints "Karadži?, Vuk Stefanovi?, 1787-1864" but should print "Karadžić, Vuk Stefanović, 1787-1864"

I'm pretty sure that the encoding is ok (UTF-8) but the c with acute isn't encoded properly.

Still, browsers do show the correct char, Jsoup doesn't. Why?

Regards,
Hans

Comment: What are you running this program in, an IDE or a console? It is likely that whatever you are using to print into does not support display of UTF-8.

Comment: the z with caron is ok...

Comment: I had a similar problem in Netbeans but when I set the project encoding to UTF-8 it printed just fine, so I still think it is the encoding of your display that is not set to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you haven't said what you are running your program in it is difficult to give a definitive answer, but basically there is nothing wrong with your code. JSoup is not responsible for your display problem, whichever console you are displaying on is the problem.

If you set your console (or IDE) to the UTF-8 encoding it should display correctly.

Comment: the console is set to UTF-8 encoding, and, as I said most characters are ok (the z with caron in the name) only this c with acute isn't.Browsers show the correct char, Jsoup not

Comment: @Vruchtvet Then it may be your consoles font, but your code works fine for me in Netbeans.

Comment: No worries, glad it's ok. Please tick the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code on my own IDEA,and the output was just as you expected.
So I insist that the encoding is the problem.